# Increasing speed of text extraction of Tesseract using OpenCL

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, opencl, tesseract

I understand that Tesseract already uses OpenCL to offload some of the compute intensive modules to the GPU or spreads it across available cores of the CPU. Now if I split an image into multiple parts and send it for Tesseract text extraction, will I get any more speed up?

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on your hardware architecture. If you for example have multiple GPUs in your machine, the you could configure two Tesseract instances so that one uses one and the other uses the other. A common case is when you have an Intel HD Graphics 4xxx that comes with the Intel core processor, and you have an additional dedicated GPU. Still, if you don't have the exact same devices, load ballancing will not be a trivial task.